# problems with unity and gnome classic desktops - how to reinstall and clean them

Tags: unity, software-installation, desktop-environments, gnome-classic, cleanup

I have ubuntu 12.04.02 and I always use kde 4.10.1. Sometimes I need to switch to unity or gnome classic (with effects), the problem is that when I log in with one of them I can't access "settings menu" or other menus because they do not appear. I think I have messed up some time ago but I don't remember. Maybe it is a problem related to compiz.

I have tried to use `unity --reset` and
`rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity` commands to reset gnome2 and unity but still the same thing.

So is there a way to reinstall **compiz** or **gnome classic** and **unity** in order to clean them like when I have installed ubuntu first time?
(I just would like to reinstall them without making any changes to kde desktop.)